# dwv DICOM viewer error: "Cannot append a slice with different number of columns"

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am trying to build a dicom viewer using dwv js
https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv

integrating with Swiper JS slider http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#methods

**Functions**:
When user clicks on a thumbnail then it loads a new array or URLs.

```
dicom.init({
    "containerDivId": container_id,
    "fitToWindow": true,
    "gui": ["tool"],
    "tools": ['Scroll', 'ZoomAndPan'],
    "isMobile": true,
});



var dicom_thumbnail_swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  mousewheel: true,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 2,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.dicom-button-next',
    prevEl: '.dicom-button-prev',
  }
});


dicom_thumbnail_swiper.on('slideChange', function(event) {
var active_index = dicom_thumbnail_swiper.activeIndex;

if(active_index !== undefined && active_index !== null) {
  // Slide is changed
  dicom.loadURLs(data[active_index].files);
}
});
```

**Issue**:
However I keep getting this error **Cannot append a slice with different number of columns** or **Cannot append a slice with different SeriesInstanceUID** especially when the current array of URLs of dcm files have not finished loading ( inspecting from Google Chrome dev tool network ) before switching to a new thumbnail.

I have tried many ways including but none is working.. is it the problem with my code or the DCM files????

**Methods I have tried:**

Fake the ctrl-x to cancel image loading cause in source code it shows that it cancels the async loading when user press ctrl + x

```
var e = new Event("keydown");
e.keyCode = 88;
e.which = e.keyCode;
e.altKey = false;
e.ctrlKey = true;
e.shiftKey = false;
e.metaKey = false;
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Clear the canvas

```
dicom.getImageLayer().clear();
```

I've tried to disable the Swiper while dicom viewer are loading urls but I still get same error sometimes

```
dicom.addEventListener('load-start', function(){
  console.log('load start');
  dicom_thumbnail_swiper.allowSlideNext = false;
  dicom_thumbnail_swiper.allowSlidePrev = false;
  dicom_thumbnail_swiper.detachEvents()
});
dicom.addEventListener('load-end', function(){
  console.log('load end');
  dicom_thumbnail_swiper.allowSlideNext = true;
  dicom_thumbnail_swiper.allowSlidePrev = true;
});
```

**Here is the project URL**
http://mripro.plot.net.au/#/case

**GitHub ticket**
https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv/issues/433

Answer (score 0):

I added an `abortLoad` method to the application class to handle the switch between cases. It is available from version 0.22.1.

In your case, you must update your `slideChange` event handler to something like:

```
dicom_thumbnail_swiper.on('slideChange', function(event) {
    var active_index = dicom_thumbnail_swiper.activeIndex;

    if(active_index !== undefined && active_index !== null) {

        // reset app
        dicom.abortLoad();
        dicom.reset();

        // Slide is changed
        dicom.loadURLs(data[active_index].files);
    }
});
```

More details on the github issue page: https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv/issues/433.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)